# Wrong result with regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Any idea why the regular expression below cuts the 'fl' part of the sentence ?

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', '\nFor a this river, the ﬂow becomes complicated in the ﬂoodplain')
```

This is the result I get :

```
'For a this river  the  ow becomes complicated in the  oodplain'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing all non-alphabetical characters with whitespace.

In your code, the 'fl' is actually `ﬂ` - a single unicode (non-AZ) character, so it is being removed, along with the punctuation.

Comment: OK.. and how come it considers 'fl' as a single unicode non-AZ character, as opposed to 'th' (in this) for example ?

Comment: This character in question is 'latin small ligature fl'. This is not any of the characters in `A-Za-z`, just as '2' or '@' aren't either: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb02/index.htm